# ASP.NET MVC 5 Startup.cs Global.asax

Tags: global-asax, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

Why is there a startup.cs file in ASP.NET MVC 5? Why isn't it in Global.asax?

I try move part regarding authentication to Global.asax, because I want use Dependency Injection and I can't. I exhausted all my idea.